# Converter uma List de Objetos para UTF-8 em java

Tags: java, jsp

Estou fazendo um sistema Utilizando java jsp, usando *webservice* RESTful, onde eu apenas consumo dados de um *webservice* através de um *link*. Depois na pagina principal, eu crio uma lista de objetos vindo do *webservice*, uso o gson do Google para gerar a minha lista de objetos. O problema é que depois de gerar essa lista, tenho o problema de acentuação nas palavras desta lista de objetos.

Gostaria de saber como eu posso converter essa lista para que os acentos estejam corretos?

```
<%
  HttpExemplo teste = new HttpExemplo();
  String json = teste.sendGet();
  final Gson gson = new Gson();

  List<Cidade> cidade = gson.fromJson(json, List.class);
  if (tes != null) {
    Cidade city = new Cidade(tes);
    if (cidade.contains(city)) {
      city = cidade.get(cidade.indexOf(city));
    }
    out.println(city.getEstado());
  }
%>
```

Comment: Poste por favor o código da classe `HttpExemplo`.

Comment: Você pode tentar o seguinte : 

String json = teste.sendGet();
String jsonUTF8 = new String(json.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));